# Query Active Directory using logged on users credentials Python3

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, active-directory, credentials

I'm creating a small application that queries Active Directory for computer names. Currently I am using the ldap3 module since it seems to one of the few supporting Python3, but I am open to alternatives.

Is there any way to use the currently logged on users credentials to authenticate to the LDAP server?

This way a user can run the program and get the computer names if they're logged in as a domain user, without having to enter their username/password each time.

More info about my environment:

- Windows Domain
- Python 3.4
- Modules: ldap3, pywin32, pyqt4